# PHP regex to extract both open parenthesis and the following text

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to detect initial open parenthesis on the incoming word and if so, extract also the text preceding.

For instance:

One possible incoming word could be:

> (original

The idea is to have on the one hand the open parenthesis

> "("

and on the other hand

> "original"

This is what I currently have:

```
preg_match('/(\()(\w+)/', $input_line, $output_array);
```

which match in this way:

```
array(3
0   =>  (original
1   =>  (
2   =>  original
)
```

I'm struggling with making it return something like:

```
array(2
0   =>  (
1   =>  original
)
```

I know that it can be done using `strpos` and from there split, but furthermore, it won't be only the open parenthesis but curly braces, etc... so regex should match several chars.

What I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: I see, I can deal with it. I was not fully aware of 0 always was the full match. Thanks!

Comment: For the string the string `'(original'`, the regular expression `(?<=\()\w+` matches `'original'`. You say you want to also match the left parenthesis, but why, considering that there would not have been a match of `'original'` had it not been preceded by a left parenthesis? In other words, there is no point to matching the left parenthesis. Simply infer in your code that it's there if there's a match.

Comment: I think in your title you want "...and the following text".

Comment: Always there is a reason, and yes it is needed to reconstruct the original sentence. I.e: "this is a title (original mix)". I have not introduced the whole picture. But thanks!

Comment: @CarySwoveland Absolutely! Changed!

Comment: You just need to get rid of the first item, `array_shift($output_array);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the output that you want changing the pattern to using a capture group in a positive lookahead for the `\w+`, and match the `(`

```
preg_match('/\((?=(\w+))/', "(original", $output_array);
print_r($output_array);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => (
    [1] => original
)
```

Comment: Thanks @The fourth bird! Just a quick question, how would you add an optional closing parenthesis at the end? So it allows (original and (original) ?

Comment: @Albeis Like this `\((?=(\w+\)?))` See https://regex101.com/r/q449UC/1

Answer (score 1):

The `0` index is the full matched pattern. Each indice after that is a capture group.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

> $matches[0] will contain the text that matched the full pattern, $matches[1] will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on.